# BUG: Unable to flag question as a duplicate, selection code has issues

Tags: bug, questions, flagging

When trying to flag a question as a duplicate I followed the choices of radio selections to the end but it won't post the flag.  It only deselects the radio select and puts a small red rectangle on the page that says "404" and has an "x" to close the red box.

I submitted the flag as "other" instead which worked as expected.  I'm uncertain if any other options than the duplicate flag would cause this issue.

Thanks.

EDIT------------------------------------------------------------

[image: View of problem]